# Is it possible to mock the import or make dependency injection of decorators in Python?

Tags: python

In this Python project I'm working on I need to use a decorator in a method, but this decorator is only available in production environment and I need to test the class where it is used, so I first tried to mock the import as shown in [How to mock an import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658043/how-to-mock-an-import) but it didn't work for the decorator, I still get the error:

> ImportError: No module named B

in the file I need to test.

I also tried to mock the decorator and pass it to the module as a dependency injection, but I get the error saying the decorator is not defined.

Any ideas?

Comment: As long as you don't share some code, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: What does the decorator do? You wouldn't have a decorator that doesn't have any purpose. You could always write your own mock decorator to use in the tests.

Comment: @HåkenLid the decorator only makes sense in production environment. It's about authenticated access permissions and for unit tests it's not relevant. The problem is that the code that uses this decorator imports it explicitly so I can't replace it for my own because then the code wouldn't work in production.

Comment: you can catch the ImportError and replace the failed import with your own dummy decorator. Something like this, maybe: `try: import my_decorator; except ImportError: my_decorator = lambda f: f`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Pythonic way for Dependency Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678827/what-is-a-pythonic-way-for-dependency-injection)