# Standard Approach to Adding Services to Python FastAPI App?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, service, fastapi

I define a service as a class that provides DRY methods that can be called from anywhere in the code.

My FastAPI controller has an endpoint:

```
@router.get("/health")
async def health_check():
  return {"status": "pass"}
```

I would like to update it to `return MyHelper().get_health_status`, where `MyHelper` is defined in `./services/my_helper.py`. What is the standard approach here?

Ideally, I would like to use dependency injection like in .NET core, where the process is roughly:

1. Define the service in a namespace (.NET doesn't care about file pathing as long as it's the same root).
2. Import the namespace into the `Startup.cs` file.
3. Register the service with the application in the aforementioned `Startup` file: `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` -> `services.AddSingleton<IMyHelper, MyHelper>();`
4. Inject the helper interface into the constructor of any other files in the project.

What's the best way to approach this in a FastAPI project? Is there DI built in or what third party library should be used? If no DI is built in, how do I register my service so I can at least instantiate it inside router ("controller") files?

P.S. I am reading [What is a Pythonic way for Dependency Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678827/what-is-a-pythonic-way-for-dependency-injection), but am still wondering if there is a preference when using FastAPI specifically. Again, given how REST APIs are basically built into .NET Core and there is a "standard" way (which is not just instantiating helper classes).

Comment: When I started with Python for APIs, also coming from a .NET background, I had a similar question as yours. I ended up going with singleton. In your class file, at the very end, create the instance, e.g.: `my_helper = MyHelper()`, then from anywhere in your project, you import `my_helper` and use it directly.

Comment: Looks like I may end up doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

When I started with Python for APIs, also coming from a .NET background, I had a similar question as yours. I ended up going with singleton. In your class file, at the very end, create the instance, e.g.:

`my_helper = MyHelper()`

Then from anywhere in your project, you import `my_helper` and use it directly.

It's arguable that Dependency Injection as we know in .NET is not the "Pythonic" way of doing things, but for FastAPI specifically there is a way to do it using `Depends`.

```
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


async def common_parameters(q: str | None = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(commons: Annotated[dict, Depends(common_parameters)]):
    return commons


@app.get("/users/")
async def read_users(commons: Annotated[dict, Depends(common_parameters)]):
    return commons
```

More info can be found here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

To expand on AndreFeijo's answer with an example of how you'd use `MyHelper` as a dependency in FastAPI:

Using FastAPI's `Depends` you can create the dependency *when it's needed*:

```py
from services.my_helper import MyHelper


def get_my_helper():
    return MyHelper()


@router.get("/health")
async def health_check(my_helper: Annotated[MyHelper, Depends(get_my_helper)]):
  return {"status": my_helper.get_health_status()}
```

The `Annotated` syntax is only valid for FastAPI 0.95 and above.

In older versions of FastAPI you'll have to do:

```
async def health_check(my_helper: MyHelper = Depends(get_my_helper)):
```

.. instead.